# Criterion with Hibernate joined tables

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I'm using HibernateTemplate.findByCriteria method to make some queries. Now I wanted to create some SQL restrictions on the criterion, like

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("name like '%abc%'")
```

The problem is that I'm trying to fetch one object Class A that has a relation to an object of ClassB and both classes have a field named "name" (or "id" or ...), so the hibernate engine makes joins on tables with repeated column names. How can I specify the restriction based on the object type ?

I've tried {classA.name} and variations like that, but I'm getting an "ambiguous column name" exception.

Example (where criterions is an array of Restrictions.sqlRestriction()):

```
final DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(objectClass);
criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
for(Criterion criterion : criterions) {
    criteria.add(criterion);
}
List<T> results = template.findByCriteria(criteria, firstResult, maxResults);
```

Comment: did you create aliases for classes? can you show code?

Comment: I haven't created aliases. Now I tried to use it, but couldn't do anything with it. Aliases are created on the criteria itself (and not in the classes), right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a join, for instance To be able to access the fields of the user:

```
String username ="spnbldk";
criteria.createAlias("user", "u");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("u.name", username);
```

for more information look at these methods:

```
public class TaskDAO {

    public List<Task> findByCriteria(Map<String,String> aliasMap, List<Criterion> list) throws Exception {

                Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(task.class);
                Iterator<Entry<String, String>> it = aliasMap.entrySet().iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    Entry<String, String> pairs = it.next();
                    criteria.createAlias(pairs.getKey(), pairs.getValue());
                }
                for (Criterion criterion : list)
                    criteria.add(criterion);

                return criteria.list();
    }
}
```

And then you can use it in a service class:

```
 public List<Task> get(String username) {
            try {
                // Manage Restrictions
                List<Criterion> list = new ArrayList<Criterion>();
                Criterion c = Restrictions.eq("u.username", username);
                list.add(c);

                Map<String,String> aliasMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    aliasMap.put("user", "u");


                List<Task> tasks = taskDAO.findByCriteria(aliasMap, orders);
                return tasks

            } catch (Exception e) { }
        }
```

"sqlRestriction" should work like this :

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Task.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("{alias}.username like 'spn'));
List result = criteria.list();
```

Comment: I did make it work with Restrictions.like("item.name", "..."). But I wanted to go with  Restrictions.sqlRestrictions("item.name like '...'") (or {item.name}) and that still fails with "column not found". Isn't it possible ?

Comment: It is possible, I added it to end of my answer.

Comment: What if we have multiple joins in our query and we want sqlRestrictions on column that in both table??